# TensorFlow restore model to previous checkpoint status

Tags: tensorflow

I had save the model checkpoint which contains
'cp-0006.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001'
'cp-0006.ckpt.index'
'checkpoint'

If I use

```
checkpoint_path = "training/cp-{epoch:04d}.ckpt"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)
latest = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_dir)
```

it will print out training/cp-0010.ckpt because I had train my model for 10 epoches

Question is hot Can I restore weights to epoch 6?

Comment: Yes ! You can load the weights of 6th epoch using the below command. model.load_weights(training/cp-0006.ckpt )

Comment: Thank you very much! It solves the problem